# Definition of temperature and modal kinetic energy

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I have been told that temperature is defined as the modal kinetic energy of the particles in a substance, and it is stressed that it's the modal energy rather than the average. First up, is this definition correct? If so, how is the modal kinetic energy measured and how does this relate to the temperature shown on a thermometer? If not, what is the definition?

Comment: What is modal kinetic energy?

Comment: @Young Kindaichi Presumably the most frequently occurring KE. I've never come across the claim that modal KE is more closely related than mean KE to temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temperature is not *defined* in terms of kinetic energy. Rather the reciprocal of the kelvin temperature of a system is given by
$$\frac 1T=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}$$
in which $S$ is the entropy of the system expressed in terms of the internal energy, $U$, and, typically, its volume and number of particles.

If all we are dealing with is a gas (strictly an ideal gas), then the general definition above turns out to be equivalent to
$$\tfrac 12 m \overline {c^2} =\tfrac 32 kT$$
in which the left hand side is the mean translational kinetic energy of the molecules and $k$ is the Boltzmann constant.

So it is the mean molecular KE, rather then the modal kinetic energy that enters into the expression for temperature.

For systems other than a gas, the mean kinetic energy of the molecules is not strictly proportional to temperature, though this is sometimes approximately true. For accurate work one needs to use the definition given at the beginning.